Spectrum of operator $T:l_1\to l_1, Tx = (0,0,x_5,2x_1,0,x_1+x_3,0,0,...)$
What is the spectrum of an operator $T: l_1 \to l_1$, $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...)$, $Tx = (0,0,x_5,2x_1,0,x_1+x_3,0,0,...)$?
For $\lambda \ne 0$, equation $Tx=\lambda x$ doesn't have non-zero solutions. For $\lambda=0$, it has non-zero solutions, so the only eigenvalue is 0. But are there any other points in the spectrum?
I don't know how to approach this.

This is a finite rank operator. Finte rank operators are compact and they don't have any non-zero points in the spectrum other than eigen values.
You can also solve $(T-\lambda I)x=y$ explicitly and show that there is a bounded inverse if $\lambda \neq 0$.

Does every compact operator have spectrum which consists solely of eigenvalues?
Can you suggest textbook on this, please)

For any compact operator, the only points in the spectrum other than $0$ are eigen values. This is a basic fact and it can be found in any book on Functional Analysis which discusses compact operators. You also find it Wikipedia.

thanks
@geetha290krm!)

See the first theorem here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory_of_compact_operators
